# Error 401 using Metabase API Session Token in Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, http-headers, urlfetch, metabase

I coded a script in Google Apps Script to catch some Metabase data and write it on a Google Sheet. When I make the login using my credentials the function work and I receive the Session Token.

But using the token in the script to access my cards the error 401 Unauthenticated is shown.

```
var headers = {
"method": "get",
"contentType": "application/json",
"X-Metabase-Session": "22222222-cccc-4444-9999-333333333333",
"muteHttpExceptions": true
};

Logger.log(headers);
var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, headers);
```

I test the url and session token in my local terminal using curl command and it works normally. The Google Apps Script is almost authorized and doesn't inform any error. Does someone have any idea?

Answer (score 0):

When I saw the official document of [Example GET request](https://www.metabase.com/learn/administration/metabase-api#example-get-request), the sample curl command can be seen as follows.

```
curl -X GET \
  -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
  -H "X-Metabase-Session: 38f4939c-ad7f-4cbe-ae54-30946daf8593" \
  http://localhost:3000/api/user/current
```

From this curl command, it seems that `X-Metabase-Session` is required to be included in the request header. So when your script is modified, it becomes as follows.

#### Modified script:

```js
var options = {
  "method": "get",
  "contentType": "application/json",
  "headers": { "X-Metabase-Session": "22222222-cccc-4444-9999-333333333333" }, // Modified
  "muteHttpExceptions": true
};
var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
```

#### Note:

- From `I test the url and session token in my local terminal using curl command and it works normally.`, in this case, I thought that when you test the above modified script, it will work.

#### Reference:

- [Example GET request](https://www.metabase.com/learn/administration/metabase-api#example-get-request)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried this format previously and the same error was shown. To avoid more headache now I made the script using Python and it's work very well. When I have more time, I want  debug better these case.

Comment: @Domarys Corrêa Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience. About `I tried this format previously and the same error was shown.`, my proposed modified script is the same request with the sample curl. I apologize for this. So about `now I made the script using Python and it's work very well.`, can you add your python script to your question? By this, I would like to confirm the difference between the sample curl and your python script. If you can cooperate to resolve your issue, I'm glad. Can you cooperate to do it?